# AssertionError: 404 != 200 in django test

Tags: python, django

When I test the simple app according to tutorial 'AssertionError: 404 != 200' is occured. Can anybody fix this problem? (Project name: **simple_project**, app name inside the project: **pages**)

**My app-level urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('about/', views.AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
]
```

**My app-level views.py:**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'
```

**My project-level urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

**My tests.py:**

```
from django.test import SimpleTestCase

class SimpleTests(SimpleTestCase):
    def test_home_page_status_code(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_abaout_page_status_code(self):
        response = self.client.get('about')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

**When I test, this error is occured:**

```
FAIL: test_abaout_page_status_code (pages.tests.SimpleTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Dj\simple\pages\tests.py", line 10, in test_abaout_page_status_code
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def test_abaout_page_status_code(self):
        response = self.client.get('/about/')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

try this

Comment: Then this one is occured: 'AssertionError: 301 != 200'

Comment: Oh, it works. I have missed putting this inside the slash. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I had such a problem, use this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

def test_abaout_page_status_code(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse("about"))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a few more words to help explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try this:

```
from django.urls import  reverse, resolve

from django.test import SimpleTestCase
from .views import  HomePageView,AboutPageView

class SimpleTests(SimpleTestCase):

    def test_home_page_status_code(self):
        path = reverse("home")


        self.assertEquals(resolve(path).func.view_class, HomePageView)

        response = self.client.get(path)

        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_abaout_page_status_code(self):
        path = reverse("about")

        self.assertEquals(resolve(path).func.view_class, AboutPageView)

        response = self.client.get(path)

        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you forgot like I did. remember to add / to your links:

```
def test_post_detail_view(self):
    response = self.client.get('/post/1/')
    no_response = self.client.get('/post/100000/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(no_response.status_code, 404)
    self.assertContains(response, 'A good title')
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'post_detail.html')
```

before:

```
def test_post_detail_view(self):
    response = self.client.get('post/1/')
    no_response = self.client.get('/post/100000/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(no_response.status_code, 404)
    self.assertContains(response, 'A good title')
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'post_detail.html')
```

Since it seems like it's hard to find, i'm talking about the first "/" on:('/post/1/').

Thanks for telling me to improve my answers!

Comment: You might want to point out, that it is about the leading slash in the second line. Otherwise this is a little hard to read.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**Use mine code bro, this will definitely work!!**

```
from django.test import TestCase

def test_home_page_status_code(self):
    response = self.client.get('/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
def test_about_page_status_code(self):
    response = self.client.get('/about/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```